# Using Jade That Comes With Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, npm, pug, require

So I've got a project that uses Express.js and Jade.  There are a few Jade snippets that I use to create HTML inside the Node.js app.

## Example:

```
var jade = require('jade');

var jadeStr = jade.compile('<h1 class="#{ var.class }">var.heading</h1>');
var jadeObj = { class: "heading", heading: "Example heading text."};

var htmlString = jadeStr(jadeObj);
// use htmlString for a log or error message or whatever
```

Right now my `package.json` file includes both Express.js and Jade, I'd prefer to rely on Express to supply the Jade package, as I don't want to worry about keeping Express and Jade versions in-sync.

When I remove Jade from my `package.json`, it errors that it can't find the Jade library.  Is there a way of getting the Jade library used by Express.js without including it separately in my `package.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In express 3.4, jade is specified in `devDependencies`, which means it won't get installed when you run `npm install express`; you are required to install it yourself. However, since it's unlikely that express will break backwards compatibility with jade very often, there is no need to update it.

Comment: Well that would explain it!  I thought it was a hard dependency, apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

You could move jade from devDependencies to dependencies in the express module package.json inside node_modules.

[image]

Comment: Hmm if I were to do that, I might as well `npm shrinkwrap` everything and handle it there.  I don't think this is a good solution for what I'm looking for, however.